# Any good tools to make 3D data visualizations for Big Data?

Tags: 3d, data-visualization, bigdata, graph-visualization

I don't know if you have seen this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9wcvFkWpsM.

I wonder what kind of tools did the presenter use to create those powerful 3D visulizations? Can anyone please suggest some? I am working on a big data project, I really want to build some fancy and creative visualizations of the data.

Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, check out [Processing](http://www.processing.org/) and [Cascade](http://nytlabs.com/projects/cascade.html), Jer Thorp developed these tools for data visualization, as he claimed [in his blog](http://blog.blprnt.com/blog/blprnt/new-year-new-company-introducing-the-office-for-creative-research). The screenshots look similar to what you seen in the video.

Then, check out his post [Your Random Numbers – Getting Started with Processing and Data Visualization](http://blog.blprnt.com/blog/blprnt/your-random-numbers-getting-started-with-processing-and-data-visualization) where he explains in detail howto start with data visualization using the Visualization tool [Processing](http://www.processing.org/).

Furthermore, You could use Prefuse, see [Prefuse: A Toolkit for Interactive Information Visualization](http://bid.berkeley.edu/papers/chi_2005/prefuse/) and [Software Design Patterns for Information Visualization](http://bid.berkeley.edu/papers/infovis_2006/infovis_design_patterns/)

Also, in the comments of that youtube video they recommend:

> depending on how much you are willing to code, there are plenty of open source libraries around for visualizing data: flash library FLARE, D3.js, protovis, R programming,Prefuse, Prefuse Flare, Impure, Mondrian, Processing.js, Python etc